# Undefined Index exception in Custom module form submit data

Tags: magento2, module, form-validation

[image]

getting an exception while submitting data in form but data is saving in the database? how to remove that undefined exception
This is the controller code

```
<?php
namespace Quadone\Caregiver\Controller\Outside;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Add extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []) 
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;   
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $Customer_id = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $item = $this->_objectManager->create("Quadone\Caregiver\Model\Caregiver");
        $item->setData('customer_id', $Customer_id);
        $item->setData('name',$post['name']);
        $item->setData('phone',$post['phonenumber']);
        $item->setData('email',$post['email']);
        $item->setData('reason',$post['reason']);
        $item->setData('behalf patient',$post['behalfpatient']);
        $item->setData('disclaimer', $post['disclaimer']);
        $item->save();
        $this->_redirect('*/*/*');
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Caregiver is added successfully.'));   
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually have issue in your controller - kindly share the code show its helps us to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: I have updated question with controller code